# Is It Possible to Install Windows 7 on a GUID Partition Table Disk?

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, macbook-pro, osx-lion, windows-installation

I am trying to install Windows 7 on GUID partition table on my MAC BOOK PRO machine, before I start I have few questions:

- is it possible to do this?
- any issues that I might encounter while doing it and what counter measures should I take?
- And after installation will there be any change in behavior for applications like Visual Studio, SQL server or any other windows application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes (Since Vista on x64/64-bit editions of Windows **ONLY**)
2. If you do it from Bootcamp, and follow the guides, there shouldn't be a problem.
3. No problems what so ever... Only remote problem is SQL doesn't like being installed on a compressed drive, but you get that MBR or GUID.